# React Infinite scroll not working & when does it is looping & gave response "Maximum limit exceed error"

Tags: reactjs, infinite-scroll

I have a chat component in which i used React-infinite-Scroller. But my code is not working properly.
I am using offset & limit for pagination on backend. So i have to pass them in  data.get request & in response i am getting only totalChatMessagesCount. So i have to implement whole logic in the React.
Here is an example of My code.
Please point out the corrections it needed. Also please explain how to set offset for it.

ChatBox Component:-

```
this.state = {
    hasMoreItems: true,
    limit: 5,
    offset: 0,
    messages: []

}
loader() {
        return ( < div className = "loader" > Loading... < /div>);
        };

        getPrevChat() {
            //API called & got messages in Response
            this.setState({
                messages: parsedResponse
            })
        }


        fetchMessages(page) {

            console.log('from infinite scroll', page);
            if (this.state.messagesCount != null || 0) {

                this.setState({
                    offset: (page - 1) * this.state.limit,
                    hasMore: true
                }, () => {
                    this.getPrevChat();
                });
            }
        }

        render() {
                return ( < InfiniteScroll pageStart = {
                            1
                        }
                        loadMore = {
                            this.fetchMessages.bind(this)
                        }
                        hasMore = {
                            hasMoreItems
                        }
                        loader = {
                            this.loader()
                        }
                        isReverse = {
                            isReverse
                        } > {
                            this.state.messages.map((messages, i) => ( < p key = {
                                        i
                                    } > {
                                        messages.message
                                    } < /p>))} <
                                    /InfiniteScroll>)
                                }
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: You're calling the loader function instead of passing it loader = {
                            this.loader()
                        }

Comment: @Friednoodles Ok. But when i just pass it, loader doesn't apper on my chat box on scrolling. Then i am not able to getPrevChat.

Comment: Offset is working fine when i checked it but now loader not appearing.

Comment: You didn't bind it, you can turn your loader into an arrow function loader = () =><div className="loader" > Loading... </div>

Then just do loader={this.loader}

Comment: I did now but still loader not working.

Comment: Could you also remove the function from setState and call it below like
 if (this.state.messagesCount != null || 0) { 
this.setState({
                    offset: (page - 1) * this.state.limit,
                    hasMore: true
                });
 this.getPrevChat() }
Your hasMore = {
                            hasMoreItems
                        } is also missing this.state on hasMoreItems (hasMore={ this.state.hasMoreItems}

Comment: Done. Still not working... It doesn't even appear on the top.  When i am doing setState({ hasMoreItem: true }) in the function, it goes in a loop & gives error "Maximum Limit Exceed"